# How to get the children of li tag in jquery for internet explorer 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-9

I am trying to get the child items of the li tag using the children function. This works for IE9+. But I need to make it work for IE9. I have an anchor tag, after click on the anchor tag i.e by selecting all, the link should be disabled. The code which is there:

```
<li class="hello" id="select_all" groupindex="0" index="0">
    <a href="javascript:checkingAllOFTHECheckboxesForTable(0, true)" class="label1">All</a>
</li>
```

```js
$("li#select_all" ).children().click(function() { 
    alert("here");  
    var checking = document.querySelectorAll("input[id=test[type='checkbox']:checked");
    alert(checking.length);
    if (!$(this).is(':checked') && checking.length < 1)
        document.getElementById('Test').disabled = false; 
    else
        document.getElementById('Test').disabled = true;
});
```

The code I have used is working fine IE9+. How can I make it work for IE9?

Comment: what is `$(this).is(':checked')` for?

Comment: what is `input[id=test[type='checkbox']:checked`... is `test` the id of a checkbox then what is `Test`?

Comment: it should be as simple as http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mzctotfv/2/